# Assigning a boxing weight class

Tags: javascript, logic, helper

I'm having problems in the `JavaScript` I have written. This script is suppose to prompt the user for the weight, from 0 to 126 and then have an alert box pop up descibing the weight they are in.

```
weight class      from    to
-------------------------------
Fly               0     112
SuperFly          112   115
Bantam            115   118
SuperBantam       118   122
Feather           122   126
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"));
  if (weight > 126) {
    alert('Please enter a weight lighter than 126');
  }
  document.writeln('<br/>');
  var wArray = String ([fly,superfly,bantam,superbantam,feather]);

  function recruit() {
    if (0 < weight < 112){
      document.writeln('You are in' + wArray[0] +'class!');
    }
    if (112 < weight < 115){
     document.writeln('You are in' + wArray[1] +'class!');
    }
    if (115 < weight < 118){
      document.writeln('You are in' + wArray[2] +'class!');
    }
    if (118 < weight < 122){
      document.writeln('You are in' + wArray[3] +'class!');
    }
    if (122 < weight 126){
      document.writeln('Your weight class is' + wArray[4]);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Note that you are missing a closing `}` on your function. Proper and consistent indentation (which I've applied to your question) will help you notice things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
var wArray = String ([fly,superfly,bantam,superbantam,feather]);
```

to this

```
var wArray = ["fly", "superfly", "bantam", "superbantam", "feather"];
```

All arrays in JavaScript are dynamically typed.  There's no way to create a string array; you just create an array and fill it with strings.

Also,

```
if (115 < weight < 118)
```

is not valid.  You want

```
if (weight > 115 && weight < 118)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first pass on rewriting your code:

```
var weight = prompt("What is your weight?") * 1;
if (weight>126){
  alert('Please enter a weight lighter than 126');
}else if (weight > 122){
  alert('You are in' + wArray[4] +'class!');
}else if (weight > 118){
  alert('You are in' + wArray[3] +'class!');
}else if (weight > 115){
  alert('You are in' + wArray[2] +'class!');
}else if (weight > 112){
  alert('You are in' + wArray[1] +'class!');
}else{
  alert('You are in' + wArray[0] +'class!');
}
```

Now, look at that and think about how you might write a `for` loop, and create a data structure that pairs the limit with the name. Then you could just loop down through your array until you find the right entry.

*Hint: what about this*

```
var classes = [
  { min:123, max:126, name:'fly'      },
  { min:119, max:122, name:'superfly' },
  // etc.
];
```

Comment: You get my last +1 of the day, but honestly, I think OP needs to learn to walk before flying :)